# Create a perfect square mask on a graphic clip

Tags: premiere, mask

I have a square graphic created with the rectangle tool (holding shift to create a perfect square).

I need to mask this square with a square shaped mask.

After clicking on the rectangle mask button in the Effect Controls panel, a rectangle mask was created for me, however I want a perfect square.

[image]

I can't see any way to turn this rectangle mask into a square mask beyond moving the points and "eyeballing" it, which I do not want to do.

I've grown increasingly frustrated with the masking system because it seems like it lacks basic features, however my fingers are crossed that I'm actually just missing something obvious.

Thanks for your time!

Comment: You're not the only one frustrated with Premieres masking/shape tools so don't worry.

Comment: That makes me worried